# Good practice for multiple similar before_filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have set up a rails application with devise as the authentication system. I use polymorphic associations for different kinds of users. Now I want to add some `before_filter`s to control access rights of the different roles. Thus I would have to define one method for each kind of user, but there are some methods that should be allowed for multiple combinations of users.

At the moment I have 3 different roles and if I would define one method for each possible combination I would have to define 7 methods which are very similar. So I wonder if there is any elegant way to do this. For example something like this:

```
before_filter :allow_user1, only: [...]
before_filter :allow_user2, except: [...]
```

Comment: Do you really need to check roles manually? May be `cancan` can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use cancan as bronislav suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try [declarative_authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization).